# Parsing a URL Using ASP.NET MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, system.web.routing

I have a URL in string format that I want to parse to get the relevent Route Values. I could parse the string manually, but I want to use my routing configuration so I am not tied to the particular string format (so I can change the URL format easily).

I am trying to use the GetRouteData method on the RouteCollection, but this takes a HttpContextBase parameter. Obviously this works fine when the URL is the current URL, but I need to be able to pass in any URL.

In my routing unit tests I mock HttpContextBase out, but I don't want to do that in production code!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you find useful info here

http://forums.asp.net/t/1281667.aspx

Comment: I did end up overriding HttpContextBase in the same way that is suggested in that forum thread.